# Error R.id && Theme.AppCompat.Light when i make Action

Tags: android, console, android-actionbar

When i Edited 
it's still error when i edit finish .this is my code MainActivity

```
package com.example.actionbar;

 import android.os.Bundle;
 import android.app.Activity;
 import android.view.Menu;
 import android.view.MenuItem;
 import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
}


@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}
//ถ้ามีการเลือก actionเกิดขึ้น object ที่นำมาใช้จะเรียกชื่อobject นี้ว่า onOptionItemSelected()
public boolean onOptionItemSelect(MenuItem item){
    //ใช้switch case ในการกำหนดว่าเมือ เลือก action นี้เเล้วทำอะไร
    switch (item.getItemId()){
        case R.id.action_search:
            Toast.makeText(this,"Menu search is selected", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        break;
        case R.id.action_settings:
            Toast.makeText(this,"Menu setting is selected", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        break;
    default:
        break;
    }
    return true;    
}

}
```

Now i add string to string.xml

```
<string name="action_search">Search</string>
```

This is my code in res/menu/main

```
<item
    android:id="@+id/action_search"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_search"
    android:name="@string/action_search"
    android:showAsAction="ifRoom"/>
```

This is my code at manifest error at (android:label="@string/Theme.AppCompat.Light") .

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   package="com.example.actionbar"
   android:versionCode="1"
   android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="11"
    android:targetSdkVersion="18" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.actionbar.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/Theme.AppCompat.Light" >          <<<<<<<<<<<error
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>

</manifest>
```

this my error in R & Theme.AppCompat.Light.

```
 R cannot be resolved to a variable
 No resource found that matches the given name (at 'label' with value   '@string/Theme.AppCompat.Light')
```

How can i do ??
thank you

Comment: i make drawable folder and paste image in folder

Comment: What the hell dude? Why do you keep changing the question?

Comment: check edit post agian LuckyMe

Comment: @ThanapoomNaNakhon The first question was about an item id not being registered, not it about theme error. Why are you changing the question?!

Comment: (i'm begin to learn android so sorry )sorry i'm fail.and now i not have any error . and thank you for answer.

Comment: @LuckyMe ,Are you Angry me ?? Y_Y

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You forgot the `+`. Change this `android:id="@id/action_search"` to this `android:id="@+id/action_search"`.

And make sure you have declared a string with the name `action_search` and given it a value like `Search` in your `strings.xml` file. Ex. `<string name="action_search">Search<string>`.

Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing `+`. Change it to below

```
    <item android:id="@+id/action_search"
```

The plus-symbol (+) means that this is a new resource name that must be created and added to our resources (in the R.java file).

Check the topic under id @

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/declaring-layout.html

No resource found that matches the given name (at 'title' with value '@string/action_search').

Make sure you have `action_search` defined in `strings.xml` res/values/strings.xml

Also change it to `android:showAsAction="ifRoom"` and remove this `xmlns:yourapp="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"`

Also are you using ActionBar Compact? If so check the below link and the topic under Modify Menu resources.

http://android-developers.blogspot.in/2013/08/actionbarcompat-and-io-2013-app-source.html